# PHP PDO: not able to connect database in php

Tags: php

I have two database named dblogin where all registration details stored and other info where a form(on the home page of user) details goes. Now I am using session to display the data related to user in dblogin but how can i show the data which the user fill on home page using session id? 
want to view the details of form on home.php by user on view.php according to user session id.

class.user.php

```
<?php
require_once('dbconfig.php');``
class USER
{   
private $conn;
public function __construct()
{
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->dbConnection();
$this->conn = $db;
}
public function runQuery($sql)
{
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
return $stmt;
}
public function register($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
try
{
$new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO    users(user_name,user_email,user_pass)VALUES(:uname, :umail, :upass)");                                   
$stmt->bindparam(":uname", $uname);
$stmt->bindparam(":umail", $umail);
$stmt->bindparam(":upass", $new_password);
$stmt->execute();   
return $stmt;   
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}               
}
public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
try
{
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_id, user_name, user_email, user_pass FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname OR user_email=:umail ");
$stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
{
if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['user_pass']))
{
$_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['user_id'];
return true;
}
else
{
return false;
}
}
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
public function is_loggedin()
{
if(isset($_SESSION['user_session']))
{
return true;
}
}
public function redirect($url)
{
header("Location: $url");
}
public function doLogout()
{
session_destroy();
unset($_SESSION['user_session']);
return true;
}
}
?>
```

dbconfig.php

```
<?php
class Database
{   
private $host = "localhost";
private $db_name = "dblogin";
private $username = "root";
private $password = "";
public $conn;
public function dbConnection()
{
$this->conn = null;    
try
{
$this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
$this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
}
catch(PDOException $exception)
{
echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
} 
return $this->conn;
}
}
?>
```

home.php

```
<?php
require_once("session.php");
require_once("class.user.php");
$auth_user = new USER();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
$stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Hi' <?php echo $userRow['user_name']; ?>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="profile.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;View Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php?logout=true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:80px;">
<div class="container">
<label class="h5">welcome : <?php print($userRow['user_name']); ?></label>
<h1>
<a href="home.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> home</a> &nbsp; 
<a href="profile.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> profile</a></h1>
<hr />
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The-Echeck</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="view.php">View/Print Check</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Export as CSV</a></li>
</ul>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<p id="emp"><input type="text" name="e_name" id="e_name" placeholder="Payee Name" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<p><input type="text" name="check_no" id="check_no" placeholder="Check Number" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<p><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" placeholder="Amount" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<!--<p><input type="text" name="amu" id="amu" placeholder="Amount In Words" required></p>-->
<p><input type="text" name="routing" id="routing" placeholder="Routing #" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<p><input type="text" name="ch_acc" id="ch_acc" placeholder="Checking Account #" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<p><input type="text" name="con_acc" id="con_acc" placeholder="Confirm Account #" required style='text-transform:uppercase'> </p>
<p><input type="Date" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Date" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<p><input type="text" name="p_name" id="p_name" placeholder="Payor Name" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>       
<p><input type="text" name="addr" id="addr" placeholder="Address" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<p><input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<p><input type="text" name="state" id="state" placeholder="State" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<p><input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<p><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" required style='text-transform:uppercase'></p>
<p><input type="text" name="memo1" id="memo1" placeholder="Memo1" required</p> 
<p><input type="text" name="memo2" id="memo2" placeholder="Memo2" required</p>   
<input type="submit" Value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
</div>
```

view.php

```
<?php
require_once("session.php");
require_once("db_details.php");
require_once("class.user.php");
$auth_user = new USER();
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_session'];
$stmt = $auth_user->runQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
$stmt->execute(array(":user_id"=>$user_id));
$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
</div>
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;Hi <?php echo $userRow['user_name']; ?>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="profile.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>&nbsp;View Profile</a></li>
<li><a href="logout.php?logout=true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>&nbsp;Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</nav>
<div class="clearfix"></div>     
<div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top:80px;">
<div class="container">
<label class="h5">welcome : <?php print($userRow['user_name']); ?></label>
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">The-Echeck</a>
</div>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="view.php">View/Print Check</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Export as CSV</a></li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM details WHERE";
try
{
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<h1>Memberlist</h1>
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach($rows as $row): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo htmlentities($row['date'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo htmlentities($row['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo htmlentities($row['amount'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?></td>        
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

db_details.php

```
<?php

// These variables define the connection information for your MySQL database
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$host = "localhost";
$dbname = "echeck";

$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');
try
{
$db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options);
}
catch(PDOException $ex)
{
die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Please post what you've tried and some sample code.

Comment: **A:** You read the manuals and you stick to the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

create this php file to validate user identity during logging in. I call it validate.php

```
<?php
// Start the session
session_start();
 ?>

<?php
include('config.php');//this is the database connection
{
 $username=$_POST['username'];//values picked from login form
 $password=$_POST['password'];//values picked from login form

}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE username ='$name' AND password='$password'"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($row==1)

{
    $_SESSION["username"] = "$session_id";
    header("location:homepage.php");
}
else{
    echo "Either your password is wrong or username. Please Try again</br>";
}
?>
```

after login is succesfull in your homepage.html try this

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $session_id=$_SESSION["username"];
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<?php
include(config.php);//database connection
$session_id=$_SESSION["username"]; // we pick the value stored in our session

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users_tbl WHERE username='$session_id'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
$con->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

The Database connection config.php

```
<?php
$host='localhost';
$user='root';
$pass='';
$db='vet';//database name
$con= mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
if (!$con) {
 die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());   
}
?>
```